# Unsupported authorization scheme: Bearer

Tags: .net, header, oauth-2.0, authorization, yahoo

I am trying to develop a code in which users may sign in to my web application through Yahoo. Everything works fine and I am able to retrieve the user's yahoo GUID. Now the problem occurs at the final stage in which I want to get access to the user's profile.

I pass the authorization key through the header request:

```
Authorization = "Bearer " + accessToken
```

and I received the following error.

```
{"error":{
  "@lang":"en-US",
  "@uri":"http://yahoo.com",
  "description":"Unsupported authorization scheme: \"Bearer\"",
  "detail":"Unsupported authorization scheme: \"Bearer\""
}
```

I also tried to convert accessToken to a base 64 string but it didn't work either.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I [tweeted at them](https://twitter.com/maletor/status/510570317383614464). Maybe not the best approach, but let's see what happens. I am hitting the same issue; I believe it is a fault with their API.

Comment: Thanks for retweeting my problem. It get me confused seeing my code returning all the time.

Comment: There is also [a post](https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Unsupported-authorization-scheme-Bearer/1410204240593-2c6387c3-1ed2-4b5e-bf57-c853762d2eab) on the YDN. I expect we'll get a response there first before here or Twitter. Either way you should post back here if you find the answer.

Comment: It was posted by me. I wounder why #Yahoo has such a this huge bug.

Comment: They are claiming OAuth 2 is only supported by their Gemini API, not any others.

Comment: Do you have the same issue?